# Library does not find its own "sublibrary"

Tags: java, eclipse, export

I'm trying to make an addresslist in Java, which saves its contents in a Sqlite database.

Therefor (and for other future uses), I tried to create my own library for all kinds of database connections ("PentagonsDatabaseConnector-1.0.jar"). It currently supports Sqlite and MySql.

It references other libraries for them to provide the JDBC-drivers ("mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar" and "sqlite-jdbc-3.30.1.jar").

Problem: My Library works just fine if I'm accessing it from its own project folder, but as soon as I compile it and add it to the "Adressliste"-project, it isn't able to find the JDBC-drivers anymore (I can access the rest of my self-written library without problems though). Also, as shown in the screenshot,  "PentagonsDatabaseConnector-1.0.jar" brings the JDBC-libraries with itself in "lib"-folder.

[LINK TO THE SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwcI4.png)

Do you guys have an idea whats wrong?

Thank you for your help!

Ps: Sorry for bad English, I'm German :)

Comment: Jars inside Jars are generally a bad idea.

Comment: can you share your pom or gradle file as well..that would help

Answer (score 1):

Java cannot read jars-in-jars.

Dependencies come in a few flavours. In this case, PentagonsDC is a normal dependency; it must be there at runtime, and also be there at compile time.

The JDBC libraries are a bit special; they are runtime-only deps. You don't need them to be around at compile time. You want this, because JDBC libraries are, as a concept, pluggable.

### Okay, so what do I do?

Use a build system to manage your dependencies is the answer 90%+ of java programmers go to, and what I recommend you do here. Particularly for someone starting out, I advise [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/). Here you'd just put in a text file the names of your dependencies and maven just takes care of it, at least at compile time.

For the runtime aspect, you have a few options. It depends on how your java app runs.

Some examples:

### Manifest-based classpaths

You run your java application 'stand alone', as in, you wrote the `psv main(String[])` method that starts the app and you distribute it everywhere it needs to run. In this case, the usual strategy is to have an installer (you need a JVM on the client to run your application and neither oracle nor any OS vendor supports maintaining a functioning JVM on end-user's systems anymore; it is now your job – this is unfortunately non-trivial), and given that you have that, you should deploy your jars such that they contain in the manifest (jars are zips, the manifest ends up at META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):

```
Main-Class: com.of.yourproj.Main
Class-Path: lib/sqlite-jdbc.jar lib/mysql-jdbc.jar lib/guava.jar
```

And then have a directory stucture like so:

```
C:\Program Files\yourapp\yourapp.jar
C:\Program Files\yourapp\lib\sqlite-jdbc.jar
C:\Program Files\yourapp\lib\mysql-jdbc.jar
```

Or the equivalent on any other OS. The classpath entries in the manifest are space separated and resolved relative to the dir that 'yourapp.jar' is in. Done this way, you can run yourapp.jar from anywhere and it along with all entries listed in Class-Path are now available to it.

Build tools can make this manifest for you.

### Shading / Uberjars

Shading is the notion of packing everything into a single giant jar; not jars-in-jars, but unpack the contents of your dependency jars into the main app jar. This can be quite slow in the build (if you have a few hundred MB worth of deps, those need to be packed in and all class files need analysis for the shade rewrite, that's a lot of bits to process, so it always takes some time). The general idea behind shading is that deployment 'is as simple as transferring one jar file', but this is not actually practical, given that you can no longer assume that end users have a JVM installed, and even if they do, you cannot rely on it being properly up to date. I mention it here because you may hear this from others, but I wouldn't recommend it.

If you really do want to go for this, the only option is build systems: They have a plugin to do it; there is no command line tool that ships with java itself that can do this. There are also caveats about so-called 'signed jars' which cannot just be unpacked into a single uberjar.

### App container

Not all java apps are standalone where you provide the main. If you're writing a web service, for example, you have no main at all; the framework does. Instead of a single entrypoint ('main' - the place where your code initially begins execution), web services have tons of entrypoints: One for every URL you want to respond to. The framework takes care of invoking them, and usually these frameworks have their own documentation and specs for how dependencies are loaded. Usually it is a matter of putting a jar in one place and its dependencies in a subdir named 'lib', or you build a so-called war file, but, really, so many web frameworks and so many options on how they do this. The good news is, usually its simple and the tutorial of said framework will cover it.

This advice applies to any 'app container' system; those are usually web frameworks, but there are non-web related frameworks that take care of launching your app.

### Don't do these

Don't force your users to manually supply the `-classpath` option or mess with the `CLASSPATH` environment variable.

Don't try to write a custom classloader that loads jars-in-jars.

NB: Sqlite2 is rather complicated for java; it's not getting you many of the benefits that the 'lite' is supposed to bring you, as it is a native dependency. The simple, works everywhere solution in the java sphere is 'h2', which is written in all java, thus shipping the entire h2 engine as part of the java app is possible with zero native components.